# Python ascii encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I run a python script and i receive the following error

```
sql = 'insert into posts(msg_id, msg_text, msg_date) values("{0}", "{1}", "{2}")'.format(msg['id'], text.encode('utf-8'), msg['datime'])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 25-31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can i correct this error or maybe caught it with an exception? Any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `text` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
sql = u'insert into posts(msg_id, msg_text, msg_date) values("{0}", "{1}", "{2}")'.format(msg['id'], text.decode('utf-8'), msg['datime'])
```

basically, your `text` contains `utf-8` characters, and using the `encode()` method, you keep it as is. But the main string (the ones you're formatting) is a plain ASCII string. By adding `u` in front of the string (`u''`) you make it a unicode string. Then, whatever being in text, you want to have it decoded as `utf-8`, thus the `.decode()` instead of `.encode()`.

and if you want to catch that kind of errors, simply:

```
try:
    sql = …
except UnicodeEncodeError, err:
    print err
```

but if you want to really get rid of any utf8/ascii mess, you should think of switching to python 3.

HTH